# Does Ruby CAS server provides restful interface for opening sessions, obtaining service tickets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, restful-authentication

I have installed Ruby CAS server and my application is a simple Restful Authentication User Management Application ,  i would to like experiment my application by providing a Central Authentication for my User Management Application , i am using Restful authentication plugin for this , which act as the Ruby CAS client .

Does Ruby CAS server supports Restful Authentication for  Centralized Authentication to implement SSO (Single Sign On)  ?

Is there any work around for this  in order to support restful interface in Ruby CAS server , Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

RubyCAS implements [the CAS protocol](http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol), which is sort of RESTful (at least, it uses plain HTTP calls and not SOAP or XML-RPC).  While restful_authentication doesn't support talking to a CAS server, there are several Rails solutions that do.  I wrote [one of them](http://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable), which allows Devise-based applications to speak to a CAS server.

RubyCAS-Server also has a built-in adapter for using user tables generated by restful_authentication as its user store, if you need to do that.  (If you don't already have a restful_authentication database, you're better off not using those and instead using RubyCAS-Server's native tables.)

Another reasonable alternative to RubyCAS-Server is [Castronaut](http://github.com/relevance/castronaut), which is a somewhat more lightweight, Sinatra-based app.  I'm working on an even slimmer version of this with another developer, and we hope to release it in the near future.

Best of luck!  CAS can be a little daunting at first, but is totally worth it IMO.